# Android Twilio How do I use these example classes?

Tags: java, android, twilio

I am writing an android app that will be using Twilio, but obviously, I am new to android.  I would just like to see if someone can explain how to use these example classes from [Twilio's site](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/java/connect)?

If I make a new Java Class called `CallRetriever`, how do I call it in my main activity while sending in the `ACCOUNT_SID` and `AUTH_TOKEN` or other parameters?

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

import com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestClient;
import com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestException;
import com.twilio.sdk.resource.instance.Account;
import com.twilio.sdk.resource.instance.Call;
import com.twilio.sdk.resource.list.CallList;

public class CallRetriever {

    // The customer's Account Sid
    public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = "AC123";

    // Your own Auth Token
    public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = "456bef";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws TwilioRestException {

        TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);
        Account mainAccount = client.getAccount();
        CallList calls = mainAccount.getCalls();
        for (Call call : calls) {
            System.out.println("From: " + call.getFrom() + " To: " + call.getTo());
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE** This is where the code will be going.

```
import...
public class StartPage extends Activity {
    ...
    private String twilio_account_sid;
    private String twilio_auth_token;
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        twilio_account_sid = booth_preferences.getString("twilio_account_sid", "");
        twilio_auth_token = getString(R.string.twilio_auth_token);

        twilio_login_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Do a post to a PHP page to get user SID
                twilio_web_view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                twilio_web_view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
                        requested urlredirect:
                        view.loadUrl(url);
                        if(url.contains("?")) {
                            String[] url_split = url.split("\\?");
                            if(url_split[1].contains("&")){
                                String[] url_values = url_split[1].split("&");
                                //Get splits, probably not necessary
                            } else {
                                //GET SID from URL
                                String[] url_values = url_split[1].split("=");
                                String type = url_values[0];
                                String value = url_values[1];
                                Log.d("*******", type + "::" + value);
                                edit_preferences.putString("twilio_account_sid", value).apply();
                                twilio_web_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logged in to Twilio " + twilio_account_sid, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                twilio_login_button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                twilio_logout_button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                //THIS IS WHERE I NEED THE CLASS TO RUN.
                                //I NEED TO SEND THE NEW SID AND AUTH TOKEN
                                TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(twilio_account_sid, getString(R.string.twilio_auth_token));
                                Account mainAccount = client.getAccount();
                                CallList calls = mainAccount.getCalls();
                                for (Call call : calls) {
                                    System.out.println("From: " + call.getFrom() + " To: " + call.getTo());
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        return false; // then it is not handled by default action
                    }
                });

            twilio_web_view.loadUrl("https://www.twilio.com/authorize/CN546428ff3127adbab58eb73db7c7dc93");
                //setContentView(twilio_web_view );
                twilio_web_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: Just add your main logic in `Activity onCreate(....)` and if it's an `Network` call then do it in background by using `Asynctask`

Comment: @MD, Thank you, though I don't know how to actually call the class in my `onCreate`.  I'm not sure what to search because I don't even know the term.  so far, I've just been doing everything in my main activity

Comment: ok first post your activity code. if anything you have

Comment: @MD I have a lot in my activity code, I'll post where I need this to be.

Comment: Check my answer and let me know what is the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If suppose i have an `Activity`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.Yourlayout);

    CallList calls =  CallRetriever.getAllCalls("ACCOUNT_SID_value","AUTH_TOKEN_value");
    //calls contains the final result
     for (Call call : calls) {
        System.out.println("From: " + call.getFrom() + " To: " + call.getTo());
    }
 } 
}
```

Now customized `CallRetriever` like below

```
public class CallRetriever {

// The customer's Account Sid
public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = "AC123";

// Your own Auth Token
public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = "456bef";

public static CallList getAllCalls(String ACCOUNT_SID,String AUTH_TOKEN) throws TwilioRestException {

    TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);
    Account mainAccount = client.getAccount();
    retrun mainAccount.getCalls();

  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, taking a look into this.  I think I'm understanding now, I just need to make the links

Comment: @ntgCleaner hmm well it's great.

Comment: I guess I'm wondering now, how do I pass parameters to the class?  For example. I need to pass the auth token and account SID to the class

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I'm trying now

Comment: Very cool, thank you!  I have a better understanding of how to use classes now!  Unfortunately (to no fault of your own) The twilio stuff is giving me an error.  So, on to the next problem!  Thank you!!